# Loop through a query to pull substrings in KQL/Grafana?

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, grafana, kql

**So I need to pull the some substrings from the following data from a query**

```
[
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247155",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  },
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247154 ",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  },
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/247160",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  },
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/247156",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  },
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247159",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  },
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247157",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  },
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "url": "https://fakelink/247158",
    "attributes": {
      "isLocked": false,
      "name": "Child"
    }
  }
]
```

In grafana obviously having that long string in a table is useless to me. I need to somehow parse the data and pull the number at the end of each web link as well as the "Child" phrases and somehow connect those preferably as a Child column (or whatever phrase is in that spot) with the numbers at the end of the web links being the data in the table. I was told I needed to "write a loop to go through the JSON" any help at all, suggestions, anything, would be massively appreciated

note: the string is different for every single item the query pulled up and there's a couple thousand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator, to explode the array.
[parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) operator, to extract the number from each url.

```
datatable(doc:dynamic)[dynamic([ { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247155", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247154 ", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/247160", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/247156", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247159", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/workItems/247157", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://fakelink/247158", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } } ])]
| mv-expand doc
| project doc.url
| parse doc_url with * "/" num:long
```

| doc_url | num |
| --- | --- |
| https://fakelink/workItems/247155 | 247155 |
| https://fakelink/workItems/247154 | 247154 |
| https://fakelink/247160 | 247160 |
| https://fakelink/247156 | 247156 |
| https://fakelink/workItems/247159 | 247159 |
| https://fakelink/workItems/247157 | 247157 |
| https://fakelink/247158 | 247158 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA82UQUsDMRCF74L/YciplXaj0m11r4Io9Ka3UiRNpm7cbLIkWddF%209%20dLJ48CkLIZebxXuaDgVEi0jsYnCknKzVa0Wo53/0Usx18AvNoWAXsaQwR22KrbfM8dhiKB41eeFmPy3vnB%20EVWwDr/WSuY%20xCxflRNGgowQfnm0fKB3692lyVZfKKGL0%209BEDRWiQDlsnG1TUHYUJSBbCwPTfXa2NYnCC0%20K/kFaQAVMiWV9mAlKuMwD5taXb/JA2GSBNIDd/BoH9fH9%209gXt%20xI/OmEV0DlIQufdG8qY2oJmT5LwAZPwQgIMOtZwAYwzsH1bGWdfvwFEZj4JVAQAAA==)

Comment: How would I pull the name labels and get the num with the corresponding name

Comment: On top of the previous comment how would I use the datatable function if I'm pulling this data from a log like `Relations_s`

Comment: Please accept the answer, upvote if you like, and open new posts for follow-up questions.

Comment: datatable is a way to create a mock table. It is not relevant to your use case. Simply replace it with your table (Relations_s )